# is it possible to set up user custom notification on iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications

I Don't Know Whether it is the right place to ask this question. But Since I have very little iOS Knowledge and no skilled iOS dev around me ... I Will be very happy if someone answers this ..

for iOS Local Notification

Would it be possible to set user custom notification ?

like the user will choose how Many Times he Will Get Notification 
And When he wants it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that's possible. You can do this in two ways, both assuming you're storing the user settings in `NSUserDefaults`.

**Method 1**; don't start location services unless you're expecting the notification to trigger.

```
func prepareForLocationServices {
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userWantsNotifications")) {
        // enable your location services and register for any local notifications you want
    }
    else {
        // maybe enable some ui mentioning the feature, and allowing the user to go to your settings view controller to enable or disable notifications
    }
}
```

**Method 2**: Always start location services, and whenever the location gets updated, check for user settings before showing him a notification.

```
func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userWantsNotifications")) {
        // send a local notifications
    }
    else {
        // do nothing, since the location update is probably triggered in the background
    }
}
```

If you're asking on how to actually create local notifications, check the documentation here; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW86